# How to decode error that occurred while calling a write method on ink contract, on the client side?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

While calling a read only method on my ink contract, I get an error that looks like following
[image]

On my contract, I have a check to throw an error like:

```rust
if paid <= MIN_VESTING_AMOUNT{
    return  Err(Error::VestingAmountTooLow);
}
```

However the error message that I have received on the client side doesn't exactly tell me what went wrong in the call. Instead it just gives a generic message `ContractTrapped` on every error on the contract.

Is there a way to decode the actual error message?

Comment: if the contract return `Err(Error::VestingAmountTooLow)`, does it still say `CalleTrapped`?

Comment: Yep. It still says the same error for every error that I throw on the contract

Comment: I guess your error doesn't come from your contract but rather from the runtime (mostly pallet-contract). What you can do is get the tx hash of your transaction and in polkadot js UI developer > RPC calls > contracts - call dry-run it to get the proper Error enum variant

Comment: BTW I am assuming you are calling a read-only function as query (but the question title said otherwise). If you process as a tx you can do like this: [Best practise](https://docs.astar.network/docs/builder-guides/XVM%20and%20WASM/interact_with_wasm_contract#best-practice)

Comment: good point, if you do not return Err, do you get such error too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the contract method before creating a transaction as it will return any possible error that can occur during the contract call. This will also save the gas fee of the callee since the query will not deduce any gas fee

```
        const res = await contractPromise.query[queryFunc](accountId, { gasLimit: -1, storageDepositLimit: null}, ...args);
        const { output, result} = res;

        if (output?.isErr || result?.isErr) {
            const errorMsg = output?.toJSON()?.err || result?.toJSON()?.err;
            throw new Error(errorMsg || 'occurred due to unknown reason');
        }
```

Note1: Please replace "queryFunc" with contract method name.

Note2: you can get information about contract query from this [link](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is coming from one of the pallets. You can tell that since it has `Module` which is an enum from [DispatchError](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/dispatch/enum.DispatchError.html).

```
Module {
    index: 20,
    error: 0x0b
}
```

- Index 20 is pointing to the concerned pallet on the node you are using.
  Go to `runtime/src/lib.rs` of the node you are using to find `construct_runtime!` macro and check which pallet has index 20. It can be assigned number or just count pallets until you come to pallet on position 20. Start counting with 0.
- To find error 0x0b, you need to go to the `lib.rs` of the pallet (with index 20) and again find the error on position 11 (0xb). Start with index=0.

However if this error is from pallet-contracts the easiest way to find the error is from your unit test like this:

```
let r = contract.my_function();
println!("result {:?}", r);
```

or wrap it in assert!

```
assert_eq!(contract.my_function(), expected_result);
```

Using polkadot.js to debug your contract is not very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that still doesn't provide the exact error message thrown from the contract to the client side

Comment: can you post what you get as `println!` result? Error will be number if you made errors es enum