# How can I decode this error message {"ok":{"flags":["Revert"],"data":"0x000110"}}?

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, rust

I'm using polkadotjs to call my ink! smart contracts and I seem to be having trouble with calls that require parameters. For the call below I am getting the revert flag `{"ok":{"flags":["Revert"],"data":"0x000110"}}`, but I do not know what this means or how to figure it out. Appreciate any info you might be able to provide. Thanks

```
const { gasRequired, result: qResult } =
    await blockchain.marketplaceContract.query["marketplaceSale::list"](
      blockchain.account.address,
      {
        gasLimit: getGasMaxLimit(),
      },
      contractAddress,
      tokenId,
      price
    );
```

Comment: Answered here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6590/how-to-decode-error-that-occurred-while-calling-a-write-method-on-ink-contract/6597#6597

Comment: Did you try the same call without using polkadotJS (sneding the extrinsic within Polkadot UI or the Contracts-U: https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [useink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/useink) and the helper function `decodeError`. [Here is the implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/useink/blob/main/packages/useink/src/core/contracts/decodeError.ts).